# Number of check-in Bags on Indigo Airlines?

Tags: luggage, indigo

I am flying from Delhi to Dublin by Indigo flight. I have a transit Istanbul, how many check in bags are permitted?

Answer (score 1):

[Indigo's Baggage Allowance Page](https://www.goindigo.in/travel-information/en/baggage-allowance.html) contains this text:

> Baggage allowance for International Connecting Flights:
>
> IndiGo Domestic Sector connecting to IndiGo international sector or vice versa:
>
> IndiGo's Free Baggage Allowance for International sector will be applicable
>
> IndiGo Domestic Sector connecting to another airline to/from an international destination:
>
> 15 Kg per passenger per flight